# Is it a good practice to use a converter inside a populator?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

Hybris tell us that Converters should use populators and not vice versa because can be critical for performance considerations.

But when I am digging in hybris code you can see populators like **DefaultAbstractOrderEntryPopulator**, **ProductFeatureListPopulator** which 
are wiring converters.And I have also find Populators using other populators such as **ProductPopulator**.

I read the following links but I cannot find anything about using a converter inside a populator or populator inside of populators:

[Wiki Hybris - Converters and Populators](https://wiki.hybris.com/display/release5/Converters+and+Populators)

[Wiki Hybris - DTOS best practice](https://wiki.hybris.com/display/release5/Using+Facades+and+DTOs+-+Best+Practice)

[Wiki Hybris 6](https://help.hybris.com/6.0.0/hcd/8b937ff886691014815fcd31ff1de47a.html)

so, can we use converters inside populator like Hybris does? and populators inside populators?

Answer (score 2):

I would like to give my point of view to answer this question. One common mistake when working with converters and populators is to confuse them.

Converters creates a DTO and populators filling the DTO.
We have to be very careful when we are going to use a converter inside of a populator and to be completely sure that
we need to do that.

If we have a long chain of populators using converters we can have a performance risk. For instance
C1->P1->C2->P2->C3->P3....

I think the best practise to follow is:

1) Be aware of the converters are already done, and ckeck if we have to add our populator to an existing Converter
(for example using the modifyPopulatorList)

2) If our DTO has another dependency with other DTO
We should ask ourselves if that dependency it is really necessary.I will decide this according to if that second DTO is used in many places
or not.Because if you are the only one who use it maybe you can merge the properties in only one DTO and avoid to have two different converters.

3) Other possibility It is to use differents converter in parallel as we can see in
  [WIKI HYBRIS - Facades and DTOs](https://wiki.hybris.com/display/release5/Using+Facades+and+DTOs+-+Best+Practice)

To sum up, the design of our converters and populators is our responsability, and we have to get the best design posible of them to avoid
performance problems.

Answer (score 0):

Basically the way to do it is: never write a concrete converter class and never call a populator directly.

But this is how the product is built for extensibility and frankly you can do whatever you like.

Comment: You cannot do whatever you like. If you wire many converters inside a populator it will lead to a long conversion hierarchy of unnecessary object creation and garbage collection.